# Preg_Replace Preg_Match to Redirect to WordPressDirectory

Tags: wordpress, preg-replace, preg-match

I have managed to solve the need to move the wp-admin directory of WordPress from:

site_url() . wp-admin/

to

MY_ADMIN_URL . wp-admin/

which is equivalent to

site_url() . /wp-content/plugins/myplugin/wp-admin/

Everything is working, after months of self-taught experimentation, and answers found on this forum. But there is one last thing I just cannot manage to do on my own.

I need to block access to every file in site_url() . / wp-admin/

and redirect each one to its equivalent in:

MY_ADMIN_URL . wp-admin/

but I cannot do it by identifying the wp-admin directory in a preg_match preg_replace, because the files are in a directory with thename wp-admin in both the original and new location, which I cannot change.

I also cannot hard code a url, because the actual uri of site_url(), and therefore MY_ADMIN_URL is obviosuly different for every installation.

To make matters worse, even if I could, I cannot fathom the boggling complexity of pregmatch.

Could someone please(!) help me come up with a piece of php code that would say:

if someone tries to go to

site_url() . wp-admin/filename.php

send them to

MY_ADMIN_URL . wp-admin/filename.php

Many many thanks in advance.

I genuinely looked right through the forums for an answer, and tried to cobble one together. But failed.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Lockdown WP Admin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/lockdown-wp-admin/)

This plugin will lockdown WP Admin. It can hide wp-admin and wp-login as well as add HTTP auth to the login system. It can change the login URL.